# Find colon separated values in text field in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data in **ELK** with the following structure:

```
{
  "_index": "...",
  "_type": "...",
  "_id": "...",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "ActivityID": "7aa89a606fb940598c1906fcc315788f",
    "input_type": "log",
    "Date": "2017-04-05 15:00:05.0212",
    "Details": " Data:  EventsCount: 1 accountId: 12345 otherId: 12345 sql: SELECT Bla FROM Bla EventId: 5",
    "ThreadID": "21",
    "@version": "1"
  }
}
```

And I can successfully use the **regexp** filter to filter the values AFTER the colon in the `Details` column:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "Details": {
        "value": "[0-9]{5}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This highlight all the accountId/otherId values containing 5 digits.

But if I try to filter on the name (I.E. EventsCount/accountId/otherId or "accountId: 12345") I do not get any result.

Details is just a string field so its content should be considered all together a big string, but for some reason **ELK** is not searching the names before the colon and or the whitespaces and the colon themselves).

How can I search for instance: `EventsCount: [0-9]{4}`?

Version 5.3.0

Mapping:

```
  "Details": {
    "type": "text",
    "norms": false
  },
```

Comment: You can search          EventsCount: [0-9]*   and have a match the number after EventsCount is a one digit number.

Comment: @RoiHatam unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: The `:` is probably gone if the field is analyzed and you cannot do queries using it. So either you do some processing before inserting the data and insert properly each of the fields of your `Details` or you change the mapping on the new data to make this `not_analyzed` or you change the tokenizer to `whitespace` (I personally prefer the first one if you are going to do some queries over your data).

Comment: @Pigueiras it's not only the `:`, even if I search for `EventsCount` it doesn't find anything as if it was guessing that before the `:` is the key and not just another word.

Comment: What's your mapping?

Comment: @Pigueiras I have added the mapping to the question.